# React navigation bottom tabs screens stack on web build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using react navigation within an expo typescript app and i am building for iOs, Android, and a web build.  I have setup the bottom tabs on the main screen.  I have it all working and it looks and behaves find for iOs and Android, but with the web app it looks ok, until I navigate to different tabs.  Instead of the respective screens replacing the previous screen, they stack up.  Here is my code for the bottom tabs:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const MainView = () => {
    const {queueList,roomList, agentProfile} = useDataContext();
    return (<>
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: slcolor.lightblue,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {color: "white"},
            headerLeft: () => <Text style={{color: "white", paddingLeft: 20, fontSize: 20, paddingBottom: 3}}>{agentProfile.agent.username}</Text>,
            headerRight: () => <CurrentAgentStatus/>,
        }}
                       detachInactiveScreens={false}
                       initialRouteName="Profile"
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Chat Sessions" component={ChatSessions} options={{tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 14}, tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="forum" color={color} size={size}/>, tabBarBadge: Object.entries(roomList).length>0?Object.entries(roomList).length:undefined}}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Queue" component={QueueView} options={{tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 14}, tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="human-queue" color={color} size={size}/>, tabBarBadge: Object.entries(queueList).length>0?Object.entries(queueList).length:undefined}}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Agents" component={AgentsView} options={{tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 14}, tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="face-agent" color={color} size={size}/>}}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileView} options={{tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 14}, tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size}/>}}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </>);
}

export type TabParamList = {
    "Chat Sessions": undefined;
    Queue: {startChat: (sessionId:SessionId)=>void};
    Agents: undefined;
    Profile: undefined;
};
```

Here is a screenshot of the iOs emulator and what it should look like:
[image: iOS Simulator]

And here is what web version looks like:
[image]

You can see here how the screens for the tabs get stacked up.  I can seem to figure out why this is happening.

}Dan